# Fastboot not flashing/erasing recovery

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, fastboot, lg-g2

I am trying to fix my phone (LG G2, Lollipop 5.0.2) by reflashing a recovery (the old one was corrupted). I've managed to get into Fastboot however I cannot flash / erase it; this is the output:

```
# fastboot flash recovery recovery.img 
target reported max download size of 1862270976 bytes
sending 'recovery' (9032 KB)...
OKAY [  0.335s]
writing 'recovery'...
```

And then it stays stuck there forever.. (The same thing happens if I try to erase it). I cannot access bootloader and neither previous recovery.. Also trying to install recovery from twrp / cwm manager throws an error (I have root in my phone though).
Any help is greatly appreciated, I am stuck with a basically unusable phone.